# how do i make my discord bot add someone to the json file if they are not already there

Tags: python, discord

I'm making a economy bot on discord, it's going to store users money in a json file. But I don't know how to make it add another user to the json file if they are not already there.

````
async def work(ctx):
    oldmny=json.load(open("money.json", "r"))[str(ctx.author.id)]
    newmny=random.randint(10,100)
    nowmny=oldmny+newmny
    x={
        str(ctx.author.id):nowmny
}
    json.dump(x, open("money.json", "w+"), indent = 4)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you assign to `x` a completely new dictionary, with a single key/value pair. You then write that dictionary into the same JSON file you read. Instead, you should be updating the dictionary you loaded from the JSON file, and write the updated dictionary back to the file. Your code should be:

```
async def work(ctx):
    money = json.load(open("money.json", "r"))
    oldmny = [str(ctx.author.id)]
    newmny = random.randint(10,100)
    nowmny = oldmny + newmny
    money[ctx.author.id] = nowmny
    json.dump(money, open("money.json", "w+"), indent = 4)
```

Note, however, that you are using JSON as a data storage, and any update, even of a single item (as in your case), will require a full read and a full write of the entire file. This is not really what JSON files are good for. They are more suited for sending data between processes, or for recording infrequently loaded, and even more infrequently updated, data.